# Select unique pairs of rows from one table that are associated to the same value in another table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have three tables: `Dolls`, `Dresses` and `Who wears what`

Dolls table:

```
Names    ID
```

Dresses table:

```
Descriptions    ID
```

Who wears what table:

```
Doll_ID   Dresses_ID
```

How do I find out which two dolls wear the same dresses. I only want unique pairs. The best I managed is this, but it does not give unique pairs:

```
SELECT 
    "Dolls"."Name", "Dolls2"."Name", "Dresses"."Description" AS "Dresses" 
FROM 
    "Dolls", "Dolls" AS "Dolls2", "Who wears what" AS "WWW", 
     "Who wears what" AS "WWW2", "Dresses" 
WHERE 
    "WWW"."Panenka" = "Dolls"."ID"
    AND "WWW2"."Panenka" = "Dolls2"."ID" 
    AND "Dresses"."ID" = "WWW"."Dresses" 
    AND "Dresses"."ID" = "WWW2"."Dresses" 
    AND "Dolls"."ID" != "Dolls2"."ID"
```

Sample data:

**Dolls**:

```
1, Vera
2, Mary
3, Viki
```

**Dresses**:

```
1, Short
2, Skimpy
3, See-through
```

**WWW(Dolls, Dresses)**:

```
1, 1
2, 1
3, 3
```

Desired output:

```
Vera, Mary, Short
```

Comment: Please edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your explanation isn't very clear.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Is it possible that a dress is worn by more than 2 dolls?

Comment: Also, you should really try to avoid escaping identifiers (putting `"` around things).  In this case, try having no spaces in table names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to get from `WWW` the dresses that are dressed by more than one doll, get the related `Doll_ID` (`MIN` and `MAX` because only 2 are needed) and `JOIN` those ID back to the Dolls table

```
SELECT d1.Names Doll_1, d2.Names Doll_2, Dress.Descriptions
FROM   Dolls d1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT max(Doll_ID) D1ID, min(Doll_ID) d2ID, D.Descriptions
                   FROM   WWW W
                          INNER JOIN Dresses D ON W.Dresses_ID = D.ID
                   GROUP BY D.Descriptions
                   HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT Doll_ID) > 1) Dress 
               ON d1.ID = Dress.d1ID
       INNER JOIN Dolls d2 ON d2.ID = Dress.d2ID
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bce7b/2)</kbd>

the two dolls are bound to be different because if there are more than one distinct `ID` `MIN` and `MAX` cannot be the same value

Comment: Personally, I'd have brought the join to `Dresses` outside the subquery - it's more likely to be able to use an index if the group was by `W.Dresses_id`.  (And probably reorder things so that the `Dress` subquery-reference was the first table, but that's more a matter of style)